# Outer Measure on a Probability Space is 1 iff its complement is null?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove the following theorem, which I feel should be true, but am not sure how to go about it.

Suppose we are in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and we define for any (possibly non-measurable) subset:

$$P^*(A) = inf \{P(B): A \subset B, B \in \mathcal{F}\}$$

Now, I want to show $P^*(M) = 1$ iff $P(A) = 0$ for all $A \subset \Omega\setminus M$ where $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Is this true? If so, how is it proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Suppose that $P^*(M)$ is not 1, but it is 0.9, say. Then there is some $B\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $M\subset B$ and $P(B)$ is arbitrarily close to 0.9, for instance less than 0.95. Then $A=\Omega-B$ has measure at least 0.05, which is absurd.

Conversely, suppose that $P^*(M)=1$ and that there is some $A\in\mathcal{F}$ which does not meet $M$ and such that $P(A)>0$, for instance $P(A)=0.05$. Then $B=\Omega-A\in\mathcal{F}$ and $P(B)=1-0.05=0.95$, but this is absurd because $M\subset B$ and the infimum is less than 0.95.

Comment: Sorry yes I got that direction. I was having trouble with the other direction to it. If $P^*(M) = 1$ then how do I show that every measure subset of its complement must be null?

Comment: @Eric I have added the other direction; I hope it meet what you needed.

Comment: Yup thanks! I was just being a bit dumb I guess